# Display Scaling Law

Tags: display

Is there a Moore-like law (presumably named after someone else) for screen and camera resolution?  My new laptop being 4K and seeing the phrase '8K' made me wonder.  I wasn't able to find such a law recently but vaguely remember there being one.

Comment: Moore's Law is an observation rather than a mathematical/physical law, and has been linked to a wide variety of technological advances: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law

Comment: Yep...  It's not a 'law' per se.  hmm...  Hendy's law is for image sensors; perhaps there isn't one for displays.  They're all 'doubling after n months;' I was curious what the n is for LCDs